# Make node fixed in echarts force graph

Tags: echarts

There is a way to set the initial position of nodes in a force graph in echarts. But is there a way to have this node stay at this position?

Answer (score 0):

Of course,there is an attribute named fixed decide a node fix or not.So you can set an event listener on echarts.For example,I set a click event listener like:

```
myChart.on('click', function (params) {

    fixNode(params.data);

});
```

The params.data is the object that you click on echarts.Then you should write a fixNode method like:

```
function fixNode(currentNode){

_nodes.forEach(function (node) {

    if(node.name==currentNode.name) node.fixed = true;
});

refresh();
```

}

This method is to traverse the node array named _nodes and find the same node as currentNode in _nodes.when we find it,we can set its attribute fixed true.Finally, we have to rebind data to echarts,so we write a method to refresh echarts:

```
function refresh(){
  option={

      series:[
              {
                data:_nodes
              }
             ]
         };
  mycharts.setOption(option);
}
```

Now,the node that you click will fixed in a position.